Resources with treatment of Quantum Optics as an application of Quantum Field Theory?
I am looking for resources which deal with Quantum Optics, with some rigor, as an application of Quantum Field Theory.
PS:I have read Introductory Quantum Optics by Gerry and Knight. So that is my current level of understanding.
